# The picture is an imprint of a photographer's imagination and soul through a lens

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

> The picture is an imprint of a photographer's imagination and soul through a lens.

Is the whole sentence structure correct? Is it "a lens" or "the lenses."

Comment: Note, this is not a 'complex sentence'; it contains only one clause. In addition, the use of 'lens' vs 'lenses' is not really about English; either can be used.

Comment: The sentence structure is fine. Whether lens should be singular or plural depends on the context, not the sentence structure.

Comment: Andrew Leach writes: ♦"through the lens of..." is a fixed phrase in English and always singular. And the fact that there is more than one physical lens in a camera doesn't make "a lens" actually incorrect, either, (a) because there is a lens; (b) because a complex optical system operates as a single lens, albeit adjustable. 'Lenses' is being too literal.♦

Comment: It's figurative and poetic.  The choice of "lens" or "lenses" is the choice of the poet.  (Besides, only one "lens", in the photography sense, is involved in a single "picture".)

Answer (score 1):

It is fine as it stands.  The picture is imprinting both imagination and soul in 1 picture so was taken with 1 lens (singular).
 Modern camera lenses are made up of a number of lens elements - possibly why there is  some confusion in previous answer.